# Combobox not displaying changing values

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am stuck on a strange ComboBox issue.

I am using an ObjectDataProvider to feed a combobox:

```
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="foo" 
                    MethodName="GetNames" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:FooEnum" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

Now I have a Class looking like this:

```
public class SomeClass : NotifyHelper
{
    private FooEnum _value;

    public FooEnum Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}
```

A collection of SomeClass is bound to an ItemsControl with a combobox template

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource foo}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Value}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class VM : NotifyHelper
{
    public VM ()
    {
        Items = new List<SomeClass>();
        Items.Add(new SomeClass{Value = Foo.X});
    }

    public List<SomeClass> Items {get; private set; }
}
```

My issues:
- Initialy the comboboxes have no item selected

- when I change the value in the viewmodel instead in the view, the value is not updated in the comboboxes.

*Changing the binding of the ComboBox SelectedItem to TwoWay and OnPropertyChange has no influence!*

What am I missing?

Comment: Set SelectedItem binding mode twoway

Comment: doesn't change anything. also setting updatesourcetrigger to propertychanged won't help. please don't guess :)

Comment: Can you please provide details of class having Items property (used <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"> )? (asking as don't want to guess).

Comment: added to my initial post

Comment: You are binding to a List not an ObservalbeCollection.  Please show  how you can the value in the viewmodel?

Comment: @Blam it does not matter, since the collection is not changed. Just the items are. A change can be done by doing stuff like Items[0].Value = Foo.Z.

Comment: Post example of actual code the does update the UI and actual code that does not update the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set SelectedItem binding mode twoway

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Yeah, GetVaues would do the job here.

Comment: I have no issues binding an itemsource to my combobox.

Comment: If you change your answer to: "change GetNames into GetValues" I will accept you answer. Converting an Enum to a string and vice versa on the other hand is nonsense!

Answer (score 0):

here is what i do to feed my comboBox with enum values with MVVM

in the constructor of my ViewModel I have this and I put my value (string) in a Resource file

```
private ObservableCollection<WritableKeyValuePair<int, string>> _traceDisplayList = null;
private WritableKeyValuePair<int, string> _selectedTraceType = new WritableKeyValuePair<int, string>();


public OptionsFilterViewModel()
{
       _traceDisplayList = new ObservableCollection<WritableKeyValuePair<int, string>>();
       _traceDisplayList.Add(new WritableKeyValuePair<int, string>((int)TraceDisplayEnum.All, ProjectResources.All));
       _traceDisplayList.Add(new WritableKeyValuePair<int, string>((int)TraceDisplayEnum.WithEx, ProjectResources.TraceException));
       _traceDisplayList.Add(new WritableKeyValuePair<int, string>((int)TraceDisplayEnum.ExOnly, ProjectResources.ExceptionOnly));

}

    /// <summary>
        /// Listes des types de traces
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<WritableKeyValuePair<int, string>> TraceDisplayList
        {
          get { return _traceDisplayList; }
          set
          {
            _traceDisplayList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged<OptionsFilterViewModel>(x => x.TraceDisplayList);
          }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Type de trace sélectionné dans la liste
        /// </summary>
        public WritableKeyValuePair<int, string> SelectedTraceType
        {
          get
          {
            return _selectedTraceType;
          }
          set
          {
            _selectedTraceType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged<OptionsFilterViewModel>(x => x.SelectedTraceType);
          }

        }
```

Comment: consider reading my actual questsion. I know how to bind a combobox.

Comment: but with this method, you will not have your troubles... this is what I was saying (writing)

Comment: you are doing something completele different. you have issues with localization. also you also do not update the value from the viewmodel at all..

Comment: If I want to change the value from the ViewModel I just had to assign SelectedTraceType to a value and the raisePropertyChange will raise and update my UI